# Mini DisplayPort to HDMI cable vs. adapter - for MBP mid-2012

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt, hdmi, displayport

I've been using a Mini DisplayPort to HDMI adapter to connect to an external monitor for over a year. It stopped working yesterday and I am about to replace it. However, I noticed there are Mini DisplayPort to HDMI *cables* on Amazon, as well. The cable's length, either 3 or 6 feet, may be useful to me. That said, I have 2 HDMI cables already, so getting another cable may just be a waste of space (pricing is roughly the same, as far as I can tell).

So, what difference, if any, is there between the Mini DisplayPort to HDMI **adapter** vs. the Mini DisplayPort to HDMI **cable**? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only difference is that with the adapter you can use an existing HDMI cable you might have, and thus save some cost and have flexibility in changing the length of the cable later.

Comment: Ah, okay, thank you!  I was concerned about any potential difference in performance.

Comment: No problem there - the performance is the same.